# Google Analytics E-Commerce Tracking without visible thankyou page

Tags: php, google-analytics

I use Google E-Commerce Tracking to track sales and offer different payment methods.

For credit card payment and Paypal the user is redirected to a thankyou page after successful payment and the Google E-Commerce Tracking code is executed there. That works fine.

I also offer barcode bills and ibon as payment method. That means the user prints a bill with a barcode or ibon code and goes to a 7-11 to pay it with cash. The information about the payment is sent from 7-11 to my payment provider and they send me a notification about a successful payment back to my notification url. It normally takes 2 days until I receive this notification.

My problem is:

In this case there is no website displayed to the user where I can enter the E-Commerce Tracking code. The notification url is a page with php only and updates the database.

So, how do I execute the Google E-Commerce Javascript on a php page which is not displayed in the browser?

Comment: Check out [Server-Side Google Analytics PHP Client](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) Interesting use case :) Comment back on how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

check out the Google Measurement Protocol Developer Guide, that describes how to send the data with HTTP requests, so you can do it for example with PHP and cURL

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference